# systemd execstart script not reading environment variables

Tags: apache-kafka, systemd, confluent-platform

I'm am running confluent's distribution of Kafka managed with systemd, but it won't recognize KAFKA_OPTS unless set with systemctl set-environment KAFKA_OPTS=...

I've tried using the Environment directive, EnvironmentFile, and changing ExecStart to export the variable first, but they all start up with errors...

I'm running on Debian 9 and my unit file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka - broker
Documentation=http://docs.confluent.io/
After=network.target confluent-zookeeper.target

[Service]
User=cp-kafka
Group=confluent
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kafka-server-start /etc/kafka/server.properties
ExecStop
TimeoutStopSec=180
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What errors were you getting? Did the cp-kafka user have read-execute status to the environment file?

Comment: I was using KAFKA_OPTS to enable SASL, so the errors were related to a missing SASL config. Basically KAFKA_OPTS is used to tell Kafka where to look for the config when it starts up, but it wasn't getting defined properly when systemd was starting the service. The cp-kafka had read privileges, but not execute